# SQL group by last name from a table with duplicate tuple

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a question from an assignment for database using sqlite3 or MySQL. The question is:

Find all the last names belonging to two or more presidents. Do not repeat a last name, and remember that the same person serving two different terms (e.g., Grover Cleveland) does not constitute a case of two presidents with the same last name.

```
SELECT lastName FROM Presidents GROUP BY lastName HAVING COUNT(lastName) > 1;
```

I only managed to separate all the unique last names, however, I cannot remove same person that may be president twice such as Grover Cleveland. 
Can someone teach me how I can remove the same person from the query?

I thought of including "WHERE firstName is UNIQUE", but it does not work.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select last names whose count of distinct first names is greater than one.  This query does precisely this:

```
SELECT lastName
FROM Presidents
GROUP BY lastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT firstName) > 1
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: oh ya, that is right. I should group by last name, then remove those with the same first name. Thanks a lot. I keep thinking along the line of DISTINCT firstName, lastName together so that the combination of first and last name is unique. Anyway, thanks :)